# Gap at bottom of website

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I have a gap between the content of my website and the bottom of the window that I've been trying to remove for a few days and have not found a solution to. Please see http://bpc.paulsham.com or the image below.

[image: Bottom of webpage with unexplainable gap]

From what I've tried, the `<body>` has no margin or padding, the `<div id="page-wrapper">` has no bottom margin, and no divs nested in the footer have any bottom margins that should affect it. Using Firebug, it seems like the actual `<html>` is pulled up from where the window.

This is a custom theme based on the Bartik default theme of Drupal 7, but I think this is a CSS issue. I am, however, beginning to wonder if this is a doctype issue, but everything seems to be validating fine.

Thank you for your help and please let me know if this requires more information.

Comment: #wrapper{bottom:0px;} in css

did you try that?

Comment: Corrected a spelling mistake in my question, but referring to `#page-wrapper`, there is no bottom margin.

Comment: Your problem lies with this import: `@import url("http://bpc.paulsham.com/modules/system/system.base.css?ljink4");`. Removing it via firebug alleviates the gap, though it also removes quite a bit of CSS with it. I pinpointed it right down to a `height: 0` declaration in that file. It's under a `.clearfix: after` rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- On `#page-wrapper`, add `overflow: hidden` to clear the floats.
- On `#page-wrapper`, remove the `box-shadow` rules.

**That removes the gap.**

I did manage to add back in the shadow while prevent the gap from re-emerging.

It went *something* like this:

- Also add `overflow: hidden` to `#page`.
- Move the `width` and `margin` properties from `#page-wrapper` to `#page`.
- Readd the `box-shadow` properties to `#page`.
- Fix the `background`s - `#page-wrapper` should not have a `background` any longer. There's one being applied in a couple of places.

Comment: I wrote up the final steps properly, they should now be accurate.

Comment: I've tried it on my local dev and it is working perfectly. I should have asked a few days ago and saved myself the frustration, but thank you @thirtydot so much!

Answer (score 1):

Go through the Google Debugger, use the select element button button to hover over to find each elements margin or padding. Once you find the Element that shows extra margin/padding add the following CSS to that element.

E.g.
`p {margin-bottom: 0px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code:

```
body{margin-bottom: 0px, padding-bottom: 0px}
```

Comment: Sorry use : instead of ,. Like body{margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px}

Comment: The `body` element *already has* `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`, so your idea will make no difference.

Comment: I think that comma should be a semi-colon.

Comment: Yes, it should be  body {margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px}. Sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the clearfix in your footer:

```
<div id="footer-columns" class="clearfix">
```

Remove `class="clearfix"`, and the gap is gone.

**Update**
*Apparently not in all browsers; see comments. thirtydot's method is probably the way to go.*

Comment: This is not correct. Try doing your fix and then adding `background: red` to the `html` element.

Comment: Its gone in Chrome, both my using the inspector and in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FjNxJ/

Comment: (Copied the code and removed the .clearfix. Added red as background to the html-element).

Comment: In both Chrome and Firefox in that Fiddle, I can see some red `background` poking through. My point was that when it's fixed properly, you should not be able to see any of the `background` on the `html` element. Removing float-clearing from the footer is not the answer :) For instance, he loses the ability to have a background on the footer.

Comment: Well, he can add a height attribute to the #footer-wrapper, to counter the clearfix, if he wants a background. Usually, things can be done differently.

Comment: If you add a fixed height to `#footer-wrapper`, the gap is back in *Firefox 3*: http://jsfiddle.net/FjNxJ/1/

Comment: For what it's worth, it's coming from the `-moz-box-shadow`: http://jsfiddle.net/FjNxJ/2/

Comment: Sure is. But we might have lost OP along the way!